# Firebase Download Image using Download URL (Without Calling Storage)

Tags: javascript, firebase, download, firebase-storage

[Firebase's documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files) covers downloading an image **if you call storage and `getDownloadURL`**, and I have this working fine (straight from the docs):

```
storageRef.child('images/stars.jpg').getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  // `url` is the download URL for 'images/stars.jpg'

  // This can be downloaded directly:
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.onload = function(event) {
    var blob = xhr.response;
  };
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.send();

  // Or inserted into an <img> element:
  var img = document.getElementById('myimg');
  img.src = url;
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle any errors
});
```

However, I already have a URL and want to download an image **without calling firebase storage**.  This is my attempt:

```
var url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/somerandombucketname..."
console.log(url);
// This can be downloaded directly:
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function(event) {
  var blob = xhr.response;
};
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.send();
```

But, no file is downloaded and no error is shown in the browser's development tools.

*Note: I do know the URL is correct because if I put URL directly into my browser search bar, I am able to access the file and download it.*

**Does anyone know how to download an image using a Download URL that you already have (without calling Firebase Storage as they do in the docs)?**

Comment: If you take a look at the browser's developer tools, does it show some error/s?

Comment: @RaxWeber no errors are shown in the browser's dev tools

Answer (score 8):

This ended up working for me:

```
var url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/somerandombucketname..."
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1).split("?")[0];
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function() {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
  a.download = "fileDownloaded.filetype"; // Name the file anything you'd like.
  a.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
};
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.send();
```

This is essentially creating an `a href` to the URL I have and then clicking the `a href` programmatically when the `xhr` response is received.

It is not clear to me why the first way doesn't work as well, but hopefully this helps others that face the same issue.

Comment: Did this work when you load the site on mobile as well. I am really glad this finally worked for me I was looking for a solution for so long. Now I still cannot trigger the same for mobile

Comment: Awesome works like charm!