# How to use Javascript to download LARGE file from Firebase storage?

Tags: javascript, firebase, download, firebase-storage

I want to write JS code that downloads a large audio file from Firebase storage. The audio file must download to disk, not start playing in the browser.

I got it working for small files using [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45453470/firebase-download-image-using-download-url-without-calling-storage), which is based off of [Firebase's documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#web-version-9_1). But this solution, along with many other solutions that I've found, involve downloading the entire file first as a Blob, which is infeasible for files that don't fit in memory.

So my question is: How can I use JS to download **large** files from Firebase storage in the browser?

Comment: Your question is not unique to Firebase.  All you get from Firebase is a URL.  There is no streaming API for downloads in a web browser.  It's up to you to decide what to do with that URL.  You can use any fetch or download mechanism you want.  You might want to expand your research to include this more generalized problem of downloading the contents of a URL to a file (which you might not be able to do).

Comment: @DougStevenson: that actually changed recently, and you can now also get the data directly *through* the SDK. See https://firebase.google.com/support/releases#fwru-2021-11-26 and the link from there. I'm not sure if it helps for this use-case btw.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_directly_from_the_sdk) say getStream is only for nodejs, so that leaves you with still pulling everything into memory at once with getBytes or getBlob.

Comment: Even if `getStream()` was available in the browser, the [Web APIs for streams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemWritableFileStream) are only in the draft stage. @michaeljan What is the reason you want to avoid [`getDownloadURL()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url)? Another alternative is proxying the file request through a Cloud Function and using that to generate the download URL (this would prevent someone just reattempting the same download).